# What is the solution when I have to use a property that is not typed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to slowly migrate to TypeScript because I consider it a better alternative than plain old JavaScript.

There might be a major drawback (that I realised now) with it - not all attributes are typed.

For example:

In my NodeJS project I want to use the npm package jwt-decode.
It has this .d.ts file:

```
export class InvalidTokenError extends Error {}

export interface JwtDecodeOptions {
  header?: boolean;
}

export interface JwtHeader {
  type?: string;
  alg?: string;
}

export interface JwtPayload {
  iss?: string;
  sub?: string;
  aud?: string[] | string;
  exp?: number;
  nbf?: number;
  iat?: number;
  jti?: string;
}

export default function jwtDecode<T = unknown>(
  token: string,
  options?: JwtDecodeOptions
): T;
```

For this piece of code:

```
var decoded: JwtHeader & JwtPayload = jwtDecode(bearerToken);
console.log(decoded);
```

I get this object:

```
{
  exp: 1645637327,
  iat: 1645601327,
  jti: 'removed',
  iss: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/supercatalog',
  aud: 'account',
  sub: 'removed',
  typ: 'Bearer',
  azp: 'restapi',
  session_state: '2434f33d-73c4-4f38-8c80-e92356380ffa',
  acr: '1',
  'allowed-origins': [ '' ],
  realm_access: {
    roles: [
      'app-elev',
      'offline_access',
      'uma_authorization',
      'default-roles-supercatalog'
    ]
  },
  resource_access: { restapi: { roles: [Array] }, account: { roles: [Array] } },
  scope: 'email profile',
  sid: 'removed',
  email_verified: false,
  preferred_username: 'elev'
}
```

I need to get access to resource_access -> restapi -> roles.

Now, the problem is that it is not typed and I can't access it. If I try to console.log(decoded.resource_access) it won't work.

So, my question is as follows:

How would you manage this situation? What's the solution?

I'm thinking of:

1. creating another interface which implements JwtPayload but has more attributes that I need - I don't like this, it would be very time-consuming to do that each time, I think
2. use decoded as a plain JS object and access anything I want easily - I also don't like this, it defeats the whole purpose of TS.

How can a situation like this be managed?

Thanks.

Comment: You can either manually write out that interface and then cast to it, or just cast to `any` (but as you say this defeats the purpose of TypeScript)

Comment: so you want the safety net of a strictly typed language with the flexibility of an untyped one

Comment: @Tom what would you do in my case?

Comment: @Bravo not necessarily. I just don't know how to handle this situation.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu I'd write the interface. If you ever want to access the object again, it will make life much easier for you (plus you still get the benefit of TS in this instance)

Comment: It's very annoying when you start out happily and enthusiastically with typescript, and then discover that many libraries don't have typescript annotations. But there IS a `.d.ts` generator option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html

Comment: the situation is that `JwtPayload` can be literally **any**thing - it is implementation dependant - there's Registered claims (which are not mandatory) Public claims(defined at will) and Private claims - that declaration you've shown are only the Registered claims

Comment: I highly highly recommend NOT using JWTs to transmit information like this. In fact, the JWT should hold as little information as possible (eg. a sessionId or a userId, nothing more), and you use that information to load the data you need. I know you will disagree with me, but I have confirmed this with several people who are smarter than you or me (several security experts, sys admins, nodejs core developers).

Comment: @RyanWheale what can be the drawbacks, and what do you mean by "like this"? You mean using JWT in general, or accessing its properties? Also, this is not my full code. I'm using keycloak as an Identity Provider and this is the token that it sends back.

Comment: @Bravo you're definitely right :) but how should I handle this situation? (there are many ways - but what's the best one?)

Comment: The best way is the way you are able to ... if you know all the properties you will be using in the payload, then define the interface yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
// describe your custom fields
interface MyJwt extends JwtHeader, JwtPayload {
    realm_access: {
        roles: string[] // a union of known types would be more relevant
                        // provided that it is a fixed list
    }
}

// as a good practice don't use var, but const
// and if it appears that you have to change it, switch to let
const decoded = jwtDecode<MyJwt>(bearerToken);
// or :
const decoded: MyJwt = jwtDecode(bearerToken);

// decoded has the expected type
console.log(decoded.realm_access.roles);
```